# Customizing logback color scheme

Tags: scala, sbt, logback

I have been messing with my logback coloring and Im wondering if I can change the highlighting colors. Right now I have this

[image]

Which is ok, but I would like to make info blue, warnings yellow and errors non-bold red or something along those lines. Is that possible? Also, is it possible to select different colors for the logger name highlighting? For instance, if I wanted com.blah to be cyan and org.apache logger magenta or something else? My current pattern is

```
 <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level) [%thread] %cyan(%logger{36}) - %highlight(%msg%n)</Pattern>
```

This is a Scala project with SBT and I use logback for logging if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, judging from the Spring [ColorConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/ColorConverter.java) this should be possible with a bit of custom code. See the default Spring logback configuration.

For coloring JSON output with Logback Logstash, I've written (shameless plug) [this](https://github.com/skjolber/logback-logstash-syntax-highlighting-decorators) project in which the same type of functionality can be added.

Answer (score 3):

the bellow works for me

Java Code

```
package com.acme.logback;

public class MyCustomHighlighting extends ForegroundCompositeConverterBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    protected String getForegroundColorCode(ILoggingEvent event) {
        Level level = event.getLevel();
        switch (level.toInt()) {
        case Level.ERROR_INT:
            return ANSIConstants.BOLD + ANSIConstants.RED_FG; // same as default color scheme
        case Level.WARN_INT:
            return ANSIConstants.RED_FG;// same as default color scheme
        case Level.INFO_INT:
            return ANSIConstants.CYAN_FG; // use CYAN instead of BLUE
        default:
            return ANSIConstants.DEFAULT_FG;
        }
    }

}
```

Logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <!-- custom coloring conversion -->
    <conversionRule conversionWord="myCustomHighlighting" converterClass="com.acme.logback.MyCustomHighlighting" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>true</withJansi>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %myCustomHighlighting(%-5level) %logger{15} - %myCustomHighlighting(%msg) %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```